# How to calculate the optimal mass ratio for a multistage water rocket?

Tags: calculation, rocket-equation, waterrocket, water-powered-flight

I do know about the Tsiolkovsky rocket equation for optimising multistage rockets, however the equation requires a fixed exhaust velocity which is something that water rockets don't have, however I did figure out the relationship between exhaust velocity and volume of air left in the bottle. Is there some kind of analytical approach for this kind of problem?

Thanks!

Comment: If you can say something about the velocity vs remaining mass it's possible a nice analytical approximation is possible. Is there a fixed amount of pressurized gas that expands to push the water out? (It wouldn't hurt to explain your  working definition of a "water rocket"!) Is exit velocity linearly proportional to remaining pressure?

Comment: Hey, uhoh. After some work I've figured out a equation for the approximation of exhaust velocity related to time(or volume)? Is it possible to use this equation for a analytical approximation?

Comment: Yes, sure! Please click "edit" and add it to your original question post. "Evidence of research" gets upvotes and encourages answer authors, whether or not it's ultimately helpful. Go for it!

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147263/discussion-on-question-by-notanengineer-how-to-calculate-the-optimal-mass-ratio); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

There is not going to be a simple solution here, since the math involves complex details of the construction, the drag of the rocket and details of separation and if goal is optimal build cost, final size or final mass.

At the most simplistic, there seems to be a rule of thumb that each larger stage will have a total mass four times [the stages above](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=32028.0), so if the final stage is 1kg, the second stage is 4kg and the first stage 25 kg.

There are also various papers on the topic, going to [various](https://rocketsim.wordpress.com/2017/05/07/performance-and-optimization-multi-stage-rockets/) [levels](https://www.mdpi.com/2226-4310/9/6/286) of complication.

[This](https://waterrocketsimulator.github.io/) allows modeling a three stage water rocket, it does not allow automatic optimising of the ratios but some manual noodling suggested that between 1:4 and 1:3 is the area of interest.

If actually attempting to build a multi stage vehicle rather than doing pure maths at this point a better approach is to assume 1:3 ratio and then look at your construction limitations in terms of available materials, workspace and skills (do not build longer than your workspace, or heavier than you can lift etc).

Then you design your upper stages on top of that, and optimize [them](https://www.scirp.org/pdf/jamp_2021110514043632.pdf) working back down the structure. Complicating issues here is that for the lower stages you do not necessarily want peak altitude, but peak boost (combined height+velocity), since you will be trading [gravity losses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_loss) (want high thrust/quick burnout) against drag(keep velocity low). It is also quite possible that an ideal three stage water rocket would reach speeds high enough that stability becomes a problem, so lower thrust/less ideal solution may get higher peak altitude due better stability.

Probably the most critical aspect of achieving peak altitude has nothing to do with pure performance, but getting a clean separation. Separate too early and you waste lower stage thrust and risk collision between stages, wait too long and rocket will have suffered gravity losses or even started to tumble..